# C# - Deserialization of List of Objects, doesn't deserialize the inherited properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am having a problem when I attempt to deserialize a list of objects. The all of the properties in the object are deserialized except for the properties that are inherited by my base class "BusinessObjectBaseId". Why would the "Id" property not be getting deserialized? (The following is my code/workflow)

Base:

```
public abstract class BusinessObjectBaseId : BusinessObjectBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Object:

```
public class NameAssociation : BusinessObjectBaseId
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Json Object:

```
[{"Name":"Joe","Id":"10eea25b-16aa-42d6-950a-4c28cb0537f4"},{"Name":"Fred","Id":"a913f4b4-1c82-4d19-ade8-949227ac7d08"}]
```

I call:

```
List<NameAssociation> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameAssociation>>(jsonData);
```

I get back:

```
[0] : Name: Joe, Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
[1] : Name: Fred, Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Comment: it might be because in the JSON Id is a string, in your DTO it’s a GUID, try changing it to string and see if it works. Ideally you want the dtos to match the json 100% and then you would map the dtos to domain objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've omittted the `[DataContract]` attribute from the base class. This code reproduces the issue:

```
namespace StackOverflow45198156
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "[{\"Name\":\"Joe\",\"Id\":\"10eea25b-16aa-42d6-950a-4c28cb0537f4\"},{\"Name\":\"Fred\",\"Id\":\"a913f4b4-1c82-4d19-ade8-949227ac7d08\"}]";

            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NameAssociation>>(json);
        }
    }

    public abstract class BusinessObjectBaseId
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class NameAssociation : BusinessObjectBaseId
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this fixes it:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BusinessObjectBaseId
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Or omit all `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes altogether.